# ServerScriptService.MainScript:88: Expected 'end' (to close 'do' at line 15), got <eof>; did you forget to close 'then' at line 82?

Tags: lua, roblox

Help me with this please.

```
-- variebles define

local ReplicatedStorage = game: GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local MapsFolder = ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Maps")

local Status = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Status")

local GameLength = 50

-- loop of the game

while true do
    

    
    Status.Value = "Waiting for players (This may take a bit)"
    
    repeat wait(1)  until game.Players.NumPlayers >= 2
    
        Status.Value = "Intermission"
    
        wait(15)
    
        local plrs = {}
    
        for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
            if player then
                table.insert(plrs, player) -- add de playr to de plrs table
            end
        end
    
        wait(2) 
    
        local AvailableMaps = MapsFolder:GetChildren()
            
        ["Grass,Snow"]
    
        local AvailableMaps = MapsFolder:GetChildren()
    
        local ChosenMap = AvailableMaps[math.random(1,2)]
    
        Status.Value = ChosenMap.Name.." Chosen"
    
        local ClonedMap = ChosenMap:Clone()
        ClonedMap.Parent = workspace
    
        --teleport de playr
    
        local grasstelepors = ClonedMap:FindFirstChild("grasstelepors")
    
        if not grasstelepors then
            print("no spawn m8")
        end
    
        local Availablegrasstelepors = grasstelepors:GetChildren()
    
        ["telepor"]"telepor","telepor","telepor"
    
        for i, player in pairs(plrs) do
            if player then
                character = player.Character
            
                if character then
                    --telepor em
                    character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = Availablegrasstelepors[1]
                    table.remove(Availablegrasstelepors,1)
                
                    --give them swords so they can violence
                
                    local Sword = ServerStorage.Sword:Clone()
                    Sword.Parent = player.Backpack
                
                    local GameTag = Instance.new("BoolValue")
                    GameTag.Name = "GameTag"
                    GameTag.Parent = player.Character
                
                else
                    --no charecter m8
                    if not player then
                        table.remove(plrs,i)
                    end
                end
        end
    
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you everything.

The code expected there to be an `end` to close your `while true do` on line 15, but instead of finding it, it hit the end of the file.

It is even suggesting where you made the mistake, "did you forget to close your `if player then` statement on line 82?"

Add an `end` at the end of the code block to fix it.